# macOS, Python3+: How to replace last line in console after print()? I'm just getting repeated lines. flush & \r won't work

Tags: python, stdout

I want to keep printing out to the console. The data changes constantly, but it still needs to be replaceable until it's finished.

So far, I've seen a lot of suggestions on how to flush the console:

1. `print("something", end="\r")`
2. `print("something", flush=True)`
3. `print("something", flush=True, end="\r")`
4. `python3 -u file.py` combined with either of the above, since it's buffered.
5. See below:

   ```
   sys.stdout.write(something)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   ```

These ALL work, every time, ***but*** when the size of the output string is larger than the size of the console window, this is what happens:

```
[-------console window size here----------------]
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to keep
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to keep progressively
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to keep progressively increasing
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to keep progressively increasing the
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to keep progressively increasing the size
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to keep progressively increasing the size of
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to keep progressively increasing the size of the 
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to keep progressively increasing the size of the output
Instead of flushing the buffer, we're just going to keep progressively increasing the size of the output endlessly
[flush happens here, rinse, repeat]
```

Why? How do you fix this?

Comment: It needs to _only_ be CR, not CRLF. The "LF" is what makes a new line.

Comment: And yes, when wrapping happens this is completely 100% normal. You can't fix it without knowing what terminal type is active and sending appropriate control sequences. Sometimes, part of the answer is to actively _prevent_ line wrapping (truncating lines so they can't be longer than the terminal is wide). Turning off local echo is often another part, so there's nothing written to the terminal your program doesn't know about.

Comment: ...the best available approaches to avoiding the problem involve using the curses library or some newer / more modern equivalent to manager cursor position &c on your behalf. You _can_ write code that sends the right control sequences for whatever specific terminal you're using right now, but it'll break as soon as someone tries to run it in an incompatible terminal. Do it right and use tools that can look up the right control codes for _any_ terminal, and your software will need less maintenance over its life.